# How to define Linked list on Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a new in Haskell.
I made built-in list type on the code below. Using that type I want to make `max` function. It will work with non-empty lists.

```
data List a = ListNode a (List a) | ListEnd

mylength :: List a -> Int
mylength ListEnd         = 0
mylength (ListNode x xs) = 1 + mylength xs

max :: List a => a -> Int
max (x:xs)
    | --
    | --
```

The expected output is here.

```
Main> max (ListNode 10 ListEnd)

10

Main> max (ListNode 20 (ListNode 10 ListEnd))

20
```

Comment: No need to definee this: Haskell's list *is* a linked list.

Comment: `max` already exists: that is `maximum`. Hint: something is missing in your type signature.

Comment: You're right but marking system ask that type

Comment: So, I must include first 5-line on the code.

Comment: what functionality will you need to calculate the maximum of two objects?

Comment: Anything if that is basic function. And it should be named max

Comment: but now your signature does not make much sense: `List` is *not* a typeclass, and furthermore the output is not per se an `Int`, but an `a`.

Comment: Right. I can fix rest of other code except first 5-line. The last 4-line was my attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest that you rename `max`, for example to `maximum'`, to avoid name clashes with `max` and `maximum`.

The signature does not make much sense right now. Now your code suggest that `List` is a typeclass, but it is not, it is a type constructor. Furthermore the maximum is supposed to return an element of the list, so an `a`, not an `Int`. Finally you can not calculate the maximum of just any type, it needs to have an "order relation". So likely you here want to add a type constraint that `a` is a member of the `Ord` typeclass.

The signature is thus:

```
maximum' :: Ord a => List a -> a
```

Your list has two data constructors: `ListNode` and `ListEnd`, so you can not use `(:)` here, since that is a data constructor of the list type `[]`. A maximum over an empty list does not make much sense, so we can define two clauses here:

```
maximum' :: Ord a => List a -> a
maximum' (ListNode x ListEnd) = ...
maximum' (ListNode x xs) = ...
```

I leave the rest as an exercise. It might help to take a look at the [**`max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:max). This function calculates the maximum of two objects. You probably should use that in your `maximum'` definition.

Comment: What do you mean by two "…" after '=' sign?

Comment: @Hume: that is the part you need to fill in yourself :)

Comment: Ok! what if the input is character? Do I have to change "Ord a =" part?

Comment: @Hume: no, that is the entire point of using the `Ord a` typeclass here: that for everything that is inherently ordered, you can use `max` to obtain the largest of the two. So if you define your `maximum'` function in terms of `max`, then that should work.

Comment: I tried to solve it but not working. "max ListNode x", "max ListNode xs". What's the problem with this code. Looking for max value in the List.

Comment: @Hume: what is `max ListNode xs` supposed to do?

Comment: Checking next value in the list. Like x:xs

Comment: @Hume: but in the above code fragment, the last clause has an `x` and `xs`: `x` is the first item, `xs` is a `List a` object, similar to `(x:xs)`.

Comment: yeah. So, if x is not the maximum value, we should check next value (xs). This is my understanding but maybe something wrong.

Comment: @Hume: `xs` is not the next value, `xs` is the `List a` of the remaining elements. Think of a recursive function to calculate the maximum.

Comment: "maximum (ListNode x xs)
    | x > maxxs = x
    | otherwise = maxxs
    where maxx = maximum xs"        how about this?

Comment: @Hume: yes that indeed looks correct. Now we only need to implement the base case: the `ListNode x ListEnd = ...`.

Comment: If there is only one element, we can take that value, so I guess "mymaximum (ListNode x ListEnd) = x" is enough

Comment: Works so well! Thanks you're legend.